# C# UWP - Adding object to ObservableCollection causes XAML generated UnhandledException

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an `ObservableCollection<DiscoveredScooter> DiscoveredScooters = new ObservableCollection<DiscoveredScooter>`. The DiscoveredScooter class looks like this:

```
public class DiscoveredScooter : ViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public int RSSI { get; set; }

    public DiscoveredScooter(string id, string name, string model, int rssi)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Model = model;
        RSSI = rssi;
    }

    public void Update(DeviceInformationUpdate d, string model, int rssi)
    {
        Id = d.Id;
        RSSI = rssi;
        Model = model;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RSSI));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Model));
    }

    public void UpdateRSSI(int rssi)
    {
        RSSI = rssi;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(RSSI));
    }
}
```

My XAML has a Listview which is bound to this ObservableCollection. I have a BluetoothAdvertismentEvent that gets fired whenever I receive advertisement data. I do some validation and then I do

```
 await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                                DiscoveredScooters.Add(new DiscoveredScooter(args.BluetoothAddress.ToString(), bleDeviceName, beaconParser.HumanReadableModel, (int)args.RawSignalStrengthInDBm));
                            });
```

But this causes a "XAML generated UnhandledException" and it doesn't say any more about the error whatsoever. Here is a screenshot https://gyazo.com/42ee2cae9018c05087335f77db83cb99 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem, Please mouse  pointer over e to show the exception info.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Here is the exception: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: It means you access item out of ObservableCollection range. we need code sample to repro it.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I don't understand why I am accessing an item out of range? I'm only adding one to the ObservableCollection by doing .Add(new DiscoveredScooter(...));

Comment: Yep, it's strange, may be there is other problem cause this

Comment: you could make blank sample to test it, I think it is more associate with ble message receive event.

Comment: This weird exception really messes things up. Just so you know, this is related to Bluetooth device scanning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232687/discussion-between-basse-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using .Substring(41) on a property, where the length was way less than that.